# Quartz JobExecutionContext setResult vs put

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Quartz Scheduler to generate an XML file and do something with the result. To do so I created a class implementing the `Job` interface, setup two `JobListeners` and tied them to my job. However I was needing to share data between the `Job` and the `JobListeners`.

Reading the API documentation I found there are two different ways of doing this:

1. Using the `setResult` and `getResult` methods of the `JobExecutionContext`.
2. Using the context's `JobDataMap` and thus the methods `put` and `get`.

Besides the fact that data in the `JobDataMap` is volatile, I see no difference of using either of the methods.

Is there any advantage of using one method or another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have verified your observations as correct. The only other comment I would make, after studying the [source code here](http://svn.terracotta.org/svn/quartz/tags/quartz-2.0.1/quartz/src/main/java/org/quartz/), is that `setResult()`/`getResult()` is both simpler to use and a simpler implementation, therefore the apparent superior choice for your purposes.